# Mobile FireFox has problem with fixed content at the bottom of the page

Tags: android, html, css, firefox

When I open an example of fixed content at the bottom of the page like [this one](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_ref_topnav_bottom), the content sticks at the bottom of the page in my desktop perfectly:

[image: In desktop]

However, when I open [this link](https://8oho5.csb.app/) in the FireFox in my mobile, as soon as my scroll reaches the end of the page, or if I tap the page, it will show an empty space after the fixed content, like this picture:

[image]

The css for fixed content is quite simple:

```css
.w3-bottom {
    bottom: 0
}
```

This works in FireFox desktop.

**The question is what do I have to add to this class to work completely in mobile version of FireFox also.**

I have made this [sandbox](https://8oho5.csb.app/), check the link to see how does the footer jump up and down in Mobile FireFox and not in Chrome.

I have to add this point that the scrollbar is disabled in my `html` and `body` tags:

```html
<style>
      /* Remove default margin */
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: I checked. This gap is also present on mobile chrome.

Comment: You are right. But in the real project that I used `.w3-bottom`, it happens for me just in case of firefox.

Comment: I don't think so, iframe is related to that renderer. But just copy the example in a separate html file and open it in firefox mobile. It will happen too.

Comment: I made this example on my pc, and in the snippet SO. There is no such gap.

Comment: For me same example happen. [Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/As8Jh.jpg)

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Please check the sandbox and the pictures that I have just now added.